# Create Multi-Object JSON Arrays in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

[image]

As the image suggests I need to find a way to put the values from another table with same ID into an JSON object consists of JSON-array.
This is the article [click for the link](https://bertwagner.com/posts/how-to-create-json-multi-object-arrays-in-sql-server/) I am seeing and it's in SQL Server I need to use it in MySQL.

Any help will be appreciated.

For now, I am just doing inner join within two tables.
But not getting result as expected.

Comment: Only tag the technology you want the solution in.

Comment: You need in nested JSON_OBJECTAGG (in subquery) / JSON_ARRAYAGG (in outer query). See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 5 and 3.